# Excluding period for terminal autocompletion

Tags: java, autocomplete, bash-completion

I have a slight pet peeve when I try to compile and run my java programs in the terminal

```
javac example.java
```

When I want to run `java example` and use autocomplete on the `java` command, it automatically includes the period (`java example.`). Of course, this is standard behavior as it matches the longest prefix, but is there a way to cut off the trailing period here? I wouldn't mind editing certain configuration files and I believe I saw other computers slicing off the period. It would be especially nice if this functionality is exclusive to the terminal command `java`.

Comment: I thought it would complete to example.class , did you turn off extensions on your computer?

Comment: well, there is example.java and example.class, so example. makes sense. This is on bash version 3.2.57(1)

Comment: I don't know if you already have seen http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/an-easy-bash-completion-tutorial

Comment: If the autocompletion information linked in svasa's comment works, that seems like the right answer.  If not, you could try `touch example` to create a dummy file in that directory, which should fool bash without causing any other problems (hopefully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments stated, the answer was to use bash-completion. I used the following [git-repo](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) as a reference. As for my case on a Mac (taken straight from the link), the instructions are as follows:

```
brew install bash-completion
```

and inside `~/.bash_profile`, the following lines are added:

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
. `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi
```